# Obtaining the conditional expectation given that their joint distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-expectation

Let $X,Y$ jointly distributed with the following joint density function:

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
ce^{-(x+y)} & \text{ if } y>x>0 \\ 
0 &  elsewhere 
\end{cases}$

Now, it is required to obtain the $E[Y|X=2]$.

**My approach**

First, I obtained the value of $c$ using the total probability law which turned out to be $c=2$. Then, I obtained the individual density or marginal density of $X$ by integrating the joint density with respect to $y$. The density of $x$ is exponential with the parameter $2$. The conditional density of $y$ given $x=2$, then turned out to be:

$\begin{cases}
e^{-(y-2)} & \text{ if } y>2>0 \\ 
0 &  elsewhere 
\end{cases}$

The expectation of the above distribution function can be obtained as :

$E(y|x=2)=\int_{2}^{\infty}ye^{-(y-2)}dy$.

After solving the above integration, the conditional expectation is obtained as $3$.

Did I do everything correctly? My manual gives the answer $1$. Also, is there a quick way to solve the given problem since I had to solve a lot of integral quantities.

Thanks.

Comment: looks correct to me

Comment: Sounds nice!...

Comment: Is there a quick way by which this problem can be solved?

Comment: Not much quick way unless you are really familiar. Say you can observe that $Y$ follows an a shifted exponential distribution, with mean $1$ before shift, when you can add immediately.